# php foreach -> Get corresponding data with js

Tags: php, jquery

I have a blog and get data from some SQL-database.
I have a problem to get correct data from a foreach loop and i don't know why. I will try to explain.

For each image there is a textarea where users can put in a comment. For each comment i have to send the corresponding id (ajax) to add to the database.

```
foreach($db->query("SELECT id, image FROM news") as $row)
{           
<a href='images/news/{$row['image']}'><img src='images/news/{$row['image']}'/></a>";

<div class="save_comment">

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" class="_comment_id" name="id" value="<?php print_r($row['id'] );?>"  /> 
                    Comment:
                    <textarea  id="_comment_text" class="comment_area" name="comment_area" maxlength="400" cols="80" rows="8" ></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <a class="post_comment" href=".popupContainer">Post Comment</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
           </table>

</div>
}
```

On click on "Post Comment" following js-script will be initialised....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$(".post_comment").leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });
$(function(){

jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {

    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
   });
 });
}); 
</script>
```

....and a popup Container (div with class .popupContainer) is shown, where users can finally submit their comment.

```
<div class="popupContainer" style="display:none;">
    Your Name: <input type="text" class="_user_name" />
    Email:<input type="text" class="_comment_email" />
    <input type='button' class='_submit_comment' value='Speichern' >
</div>
```

By submitting this comment, following script is initialised and data will be sent by ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("._submit_comment").click(function(){

var parentObj = $(this).closest('.save_comment');
var _comment_id = parentObj.find('._comment_id').val(); -> I don't get the correct id
```

So here begins the problem. I only get the first id from the foreach-loop, but i need to get for every comment the corresponding id. Can anybody help with this problem?
Thank you
Misch

Comment: Can anybody help me with this, or maybe tell me what is wrong (logical)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is wrong IMHO :

```
$(this).closest('.save_comment');
```

You should set a JS variable when you click on "Post Comment" with the id that you can store in the link like :

```
<a class="post_comment" href=".popupContainer" data-idcomment="<?php print($row['id'] );?>">Post Comment</a>
```

And

```
var _comment_id = null;
jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
    _comment_id = jQuery(this).data('idcomment'); 
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
   });
 });
});
```

Then you can use `_comment_id` for you ajax call

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I simplified my code and removed part of js-script. Now only the popup Container is called, where the user can put in the text and at the same time submit the comment.